# 3D matrix summation (complex double) very slow - possible reasons?

Tags: matlab, matrix

This might sound a little like a beginner's question but bear with me.

I have two large matrices A and B with the dimensions (1502x128x128 **complex** double)
I am trying to add them together but its seems like a forever lasting processes for some reasons. 
I was wondering if you could direct me to a faster way of doing this

So far I have tried the following two scripts:

First:

```
C=zeros(1502,128,128);

C=[A+B]
```

Second:

```
C=zeros(1502,128,128);

for ss=1:128
   C(:,:,ss)=squeeze(A(:,:,ss))+squeeze(B(:,:,ss));
end
```

Is it slow because it is complex and there is no way around that or what are your thoughts on this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much **free memory** do you have?

```
A = rand(1502,128,128)+1i*rand(1502,128,128);
B = rand(1502,128,128)+1i*rand(1502,128,128);

tic 
C = A+B;
toc
```

takes:

```
Elapsed time is 0.211576 seconds.
```

and it occupies about **1.2 GB RAM**.

I can't imagine another reason than memory issues.

Preallocating (`C=zeros(1502,128,128);`) is not necessary in this case. But you could try to `clear C` at the beginning.